# Components vanishing after going back to tab React Ionic Capacitor

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOqwg.png)
I have these three tabs, upon initial load everything is fine with the menu, If I go to another tab then back again the menu is gone on Home but still there on the others. Unsure what is happening. When the Menu is gone the content is still there.

Here is App.tsx

```
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
  IonApp,
  IonIcon,
  IonLabel,
  IonRouterOutlet,
  IonTabBar,
  IonTabButton,
  IonTabs,
  setupIonicReact,
  IonMenu,
  IonHeader,
  IonToolbar,
  IonTitle,
  IonContent

} from '@ionic/react';
import { IonReactRouter } from '@ionic/react-router';
import { newspaperOutline, home, pricetagOutline } from 'ionicons/icons';
import Tab1 from './pages/Tab1';
import Tab2 from './pages/Tab2';
import Tab3 from './pages/Tab3';

/* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
import '@ionic/react/css/core.css';

/* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
import '@ionic/react/css/normalize.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/structure.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/typography.css';

/* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */
import '@ionic/react/css/padding.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/float-elements.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/text-alignment.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/text-transformation.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/flex-utils.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/display.css';

/* Theme variables */
import './theme/variables.css';

setupIonicReact();

const App: React.FC = () => (
  <IonApp>
    <IonReactRouter>
      <IonTabs>
        <IonRouterOutlet>
          <Route exact path="/tab1">
            <Tab1 />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/tab2">
            <IonMenu contentId="main-content">
              <IonHeader>
                <IonToolbar>
                  <IonTitle>Menu Content</IonTitle>
                </IonToolbar>
              </IonHeader>
              <IonContent className="ion-padding">This is the menu content.</IonContent>
            </IonMenu>
            <Tab2 />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/tab3">
            <IonMenu contentId="main-content">
              <IonHeader>
                <IonToolbar>
                  <IonTitle>Menu Content</IonTitle>
                </IonToolbar>
              </IonHeader>
              <IonContent className="ion-padding">This is the menu content.</IonContent>
            </IonMenu>
            <Tab3 />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Redirect to="/tab1" />
          </Route>
        </IonRouterOutlet>
        <IonTabBar slot="bottom">
          <IonTabButton tab="tab1" href="/tab1">
            <IonIcon aria-hidden="true" icon={home} />
            <IonLabel>Home</IonLabel>
          </IonTabButton>
          <IonTabButton tab="tab2" href="/tab2">
            <IonIcon aria-hidden="true" icon={newspaperOutline} />
            <IonLabel>Promos</IonLabel>
          </IonTabButton>
          <IonTabButton tab="tab3" href="/tab3">
            <IonIcon aria-hidden="true" icon={pricetagOutline} />
            <IonLabel>Rewards</IonLabel>
          </IonTabButton>
        </IonTabBar>
      </IonTabs>
    </IonReactRouter>
  </IonApp>
);

export default App;
```

Here is the Menu Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { IonContent, IonHeader, IonPage, IonTitle, IonToolbar, IonMenu, IonMenuButton, IonButtons } from '@ionic/react';




interface ContainerProps {
    name: string;
}

const PopMenu: React.FC<ContainerProps> = ({name}) => {
    return (
        <>
     <IonMenu contentId="main-content">
        <IonHeader>
          <IonToolbar>
            <IonTitle>Menu Content</IonTitle>
          </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>
        <IonContent className="ion-padding">This is the menu content.</IonContent>
      </IonMenu>
      <IonPage id="main-content">
        <IonHeader>
          <IonToolbar>
            <IonButtons slot="start">
              <IonMenuButton></IonMenuButton>
            </IonButtons>
            <IonTitle>{name}</IonTitle>
          </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>
        </IonPage>
        </>
    )
}

export default PopMenu;
```

Here is a Tab which is using that menu NOTE: All three tabs are identical other than the value of the name prop.

```
import { IonContent, IonHeader, IonPage, IonTitle, IonToolbar, IonMenu, IonMenuButton, IonButtons } from '@ionic/react';
import ExploreContainer from '../components/ExploreContainer';
import './Tab1.css';
import PopMenu from '../components/PopMenu';

const Tab1: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <IonPage>
        <PopMenu name='Home' />
        <IonContent fullscreen>
          <ExploreContainer name="Home Page" />
        </IonContent>
      </IonPage>
    </>
  );
}




export default Tab1;
```

It was already trouble to get the Menu to render at all because of the IonPage. Upon refreshing the menu will reappear after it has gone but this is not great obviously. Unsure how this would react in ios and android when it is deployed.